# Preposition used after "do"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I am an English native speaker working as a teacher in Germany.
When marking my pupils' essays I often encounter the phrase "to do something against something", which is as far as I know simply a direct translation of a German phrase. But I cannot find any answers in my dictionaries.
One current example: "The USA never did anything against violence." 
My gut feelings says the preposition has to be *about* instead of *against* here. Is that correct?
If not, fine; but further, can *against* ever be used after *do something*?

Comment: "My gut feelings says it has to about here" - I'm not sure what that sentence is lacking, but I can't decipher it. What did you mean, there?

Comment: I meant the preposition should be "about" and not "against" shouldn't it?

Comment: It might be, Naomi, but it surely doesn't need to be.

Further, against can be and often is used after do something?

Answer (score 6):

It is alright to use *against* after *do*. *Against* simply means *in opposition to*, so

> The USA never did anything **against** violence

means

> The USA never did anything **in opposition to** violence.

On the other hand *about* means *with regard to*, so

> The USA never did anything **about** violence

means

> The USA never did anything **with regard to** violence.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the last part of the question is clearly that *against* **can** be used after *do*. *Never do anything against the law* is one example. *I never did anything against you* is another. Why, then, does *The USA never did anything against violence* sound odd, when it is certainly grammatical? We can, after all, say *The USA intends to act against violence wherever it occurs.* The reason is semantic rather grammatical. *To do X against Y* requires Y to be, at least, a neutral entity. When, as with *violence*, it has negative connotations, there is a mismatch. Compare *The USA never did anything against violence* with *The USA never did anything against any country that sought peace and stability.* In the first, *against* needs to be substituted with *about* to effectively convey the intended meaning. In the second, *against* cannot be substituted with *about* without changing entirely the intended meaning.

Comment: So the implication is that it sounds wrong because of the shared negative connotations of *violence* and *against*? Or am I not following you?

Answer (score 2):

Different prepositions get used in different ways with *do*. I realize this is not a helpful comment, but at least it's true. Of the [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions), *about* seems to me the right single preposition for the cited sentence, though, as noted, *against* is possible. There is a lot of individual variation on this topic in English, but ***do something about X*** is an idiom for pretty much everybody.

The problem is that this *do* is an **Active** *do*, a ***Pro-verb*** (analogous to *Pronoun*, but usually spelled with a hyphen to distinguish it from *proverb*) that can stand for any semantically active verb (i.e, one that denotes an action, requires an agent subject, and can occur in the progressive construction).

Often some NP appears as the direct object of Active *do* in order to clarify the action. This is where the [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) *anything*, triggered by *never*, fits in; this is one of those places where you can't use *something* very easily.

Further clarification of *do* can use prepositional phrases. Virtually any preposition allowing motion, like *about, against, beyond, on,* and *toward(s)* can be used to relate the action of *do* metaphorically to some topic. Some others, specifically targeted at this, include *modulo, concerning,* and *regarding* (note that the last two are reduced participles).

Finally, of course, the usual adverbial prepositions can occur here as elsewhere, but are not governed by *do* specifically, and only indicate where, when, how, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think whilst using the word *against* in that context is understandable, it's not the best word to use. Something is telling me against shouldn't be use when discussing an *abstract noun* (such as love, freedom, happiness). Instead I would use **in opposition to**, and leave being **against** for *concrete nouns*

I can't find a rule anywhere online supporting this, so it's just my gut feeling really.

Comment: I feel exactly the same, but it's driving me nuts that there is no clearcut answer.